# How is mongod working set partitioned among databases

Tags: mongodb

I am wondering how mongo is split the available memory among databases. I have multiple databases running in one mongod of variable size and I would like to know how is my working sets going to be portioned.

Lets assume I collect data every day that are going to be access the day after (so daily my user are querying only the last day and no look back in the past). My problem is I am datasets of very variable sizes and so variable working sets. That is with a the following setup :

- db1 - size 100 (45 %)
- db2 - size 100 (45 %)
- db3 - size 10  ( 5 %)
- db4 - size 10  ( 5 %)

Now I wonder how would individual db working set would be partitioned in memory size in memory ? 45 / 45 / 5 / 5 ?

So in my case, I have db1 that got loaded all at once yesterday night and it feels like the partition is no longer 45 / 45 / 5 / 5 but 88 / 10 / 1 / 1 (meaning that db1 working set is overtaking the memory, values are arbitrary).

If that is the case, is there a way to ensure that individual dbs would keep space in memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB <= 2.6 with storage engine based on mmap, the operating system picks what data is and isn't in memory, based on the access patterns of MongoDB in the memory-mapped files. MongoDB doesn't control what's in or what's out of memory except through how it's accessing the data (and so neither can you control it through MongoDB).

To keep memory dedicated to a database in a system with pressure on memory, you'd need to keep accessing the database (you might say you'd need to keep the database "warmed up").

Comment: Does that mean that in version 3.0 and later I wont have to "keep my db warmed up"?

Comment: 3.0 will have mmap as the default storage engine (improved from 2.6 but my answer still applies). The optional WiredTiger storage engine handles memory very differently - it holds its own cache - but I'm not familiar enough with how it manages the cache to say how it would behave in this case.

Comment: Any possibility that this could become a feature in mmap ?

Comment: Nope. Then it wouldn't be memory-mapping.